# How to rewrite the base URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slim

I need to make a rewrite rule that if anyone writes website url (the main one),

```
www.domain.com
```

it will show

```
www.domain.com/1
```

But if someone looks for anything else, for example:

```
www.domain.com/2
```

it will show the requested url,

```
www.domain.com/2
```

I need only to rewrite the base root /.

Thank you for your help,

Adam :)

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /1 [L]
```

Comment: It just won't show the /1 page... This is the server: http://78.99.138.232/ and it should looks like http://78.99.138.232/1

Comment: Oh ok, my rules was doing silent redirect (without change in URL). I made an edit, try it now, now URL will also change to `/1`

Comment: Yay, now it redirects, but I don't want to redirect it to the /1 url, I just want to show the /1 url from the base url, you know what I mean? :/

Comment: What your rule does is the following: If I visit / it redirects me to /1. But what I need is that if I visit / the URL will stay the same /, but it will show the content of /1.

Comment: There is SLIM framework, now I rewrote it only to [L] but it does nothing... It just doesn't work :/ It is not showing the /1 page

Comment: Try adding above rule above slim's own rewrite rules.